# Error: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to play with Kaggle Bag of Words module, and at one point, it is throwing out this error:

```
kmeans_clustering = KMeans( n_clusters = num_clusters )
idx = kmeans_clustering.fit_predict( word_vectors )
word_centroid_map = dict(zip( model.wv.index2word, idx ))
```

Now,

```
for cluster in range(0,10):
        print("\nCluster %d" % cluster)
        words = []
        for i in range(0,len(word_centroid_map.values())):
            if( word_centroid_map.values()[i] == cluster ):
                words.append(word_centroid_map.keys()[i])
        print(words)
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f230ff75f988> in <module>()
      3         words = []
      4         for i in range(0,len(word_centroid_map.values())):
----> 5             if( word_centroid_map.values()[i] == cluster ):
      6                 words.append(word_centroid_map.keys()[i])
      7         print(words)

TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate answer is that a dict's `values` method returns a non-indexable object, as the error indicates. You can get around that by passing to to list:

```
list(word_centroid_map.values())
```

But really you'd do better to rewrite your loop like this:

```
for key, value word_centroid_map.items():
    if value == cluster:
        words.append(key)
```

Or even better, use a list comprehension:

```
words = [k for k, v in word_centroid_map.items() if v == cluster]
```

Answer (score 4):

`word_centroid_map.values()` returns a dict_values object which cannot be indexed.

But you can convert it by doing `list(word_centroid_map.values())` if you want to index it.

Here's a really simple example of what I mean:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8]}
>>> d.values()
dict_values([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> d.values()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
>>> list(d.values())[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```